# The constructor Circle(String, boolean, double) is undefined

Tags: java

I'm trying to print out the contents of my array that has values assigned to it from a text file. However I have run into two errors and any help would be greatly appreciated.
My code is :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Driver {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

      GeometricObject g = null;
      File diskFile = new File("src/file.txt");
      Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(diskFile);
      while (diskScanner.hasNext()) {
          String list = diskScanner.nextLine();
          g = recreateObject(list);
      }
      diskScanner.close();
   }

   private static GeometricObject recreateObject(String data) {

      String[] list = data.split(",");
      String geoObject = list[0];

      if (geoObject.equals("Circle")) {
          String color = list[1];
          boolean filled = Boolean.valueOf(list[2]);
          double radius = Double.valueOf(list[3]);
         return new Circle(color, filled, radius);
      }

      if (geoObject.equals("Rectangle")) {
         String color = list[1];
         boolean filled = Boolean.valueOf(list[2]);
         double length = Double.valueOf(list[3]);
         double width = Double.valueOf(list[4]);
         return new Rectangle(color, filled, length, width);
      }

      return null;
   }
}
```

However, I had to create three new classes to remove the errors. The assignment requires that the method be written exactly like this - private static GeometricObject recreateObject(String data) . I'm unsure why I needed to create new classes in order to remove these errors.

```
public class Circle extends GeometricObject 
{

}

public class GeometricObject 
{

}


public class Rectangle extends GeometricObject 
{

}
```

I'm still left with two errors :

1. The constructor Circle(String, boolean, double) is undefined.
2. The constructor Rectangle(String, boolean, double, double) is undefined.

Any help at all would be much appreciated because ive been trying things for about 4 hours to no avail.

My file.txt contains

```
Circle,red,false,4.0  
Circle,blue,true,2.0
Circle,blue,true,10.0
Rectangle,yellow,true,10.0,6.0
Rectangle,green,true,5.0,11.0
Rectangle,red,true,20.0,15.0
```

Here is the actual assignment

```
The goal is to read persistent data from disk, use the data to recreate a collection of geometric objects, and
apply a series of operations on them as indicated below.
1. Read each disk record, create the corresponding object (Circle or Rectangle), add the object to a
dynamic array called list.
2. Nicely print the contents of the list (indicate position and content).
3. Write a method to find the position on the list holding the largest element (biggest area of them all).
4. Print the position and data (including area) of the selected object (main method).
5. Write a method to find the position on the list holding the largest element of a given color (try “RED”).
6. Print the position and data (including area) of the selected object – if any!  
The following are signatures of methods you need to write
private static GeometricObject recreateObject(String data)      
[Needed in step 1]
private static void showObjects(ArrayList<GeometricObject> list)    
[Needed in step 2]
private static int findPositionLargestObject(ArrayList<GeometricObject> list)
[Step 3]
private static int findPositionBiggestColor(ArrayList<GeometricObject> list,
String searchColor) [Step 5]
private static int findPositionSmallestCircle(ArrayList<GeometricObject> list)
[Step 7]
```

Comment: Please post the actual assignment requirements because you may be interpreting them incorrectly. You may in fact only need one class, `GeometricObject `.

Comment: I added the entire assignemnt. However im only really concernced about figuring out the first part before attempting any of the other parts. Thanks.

Comment: Please see edit to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Heck, your Circle class has **no** constructors, which means that it will only have the default no-arg constructor:

```
public Circle() {

}
```

So the error message is telling you **exactly** what is wrong -- you're trying to use a non-existent constructor. If you want to call a constructor for the class that takes 3 args, you're going to have to give the class one.

```
public class Circle extends GeometricObject {
    // you'll need fields here

    public Circle(String color, boolean somethingNotSureWhat, double radius) {
       // call the super class's constructor if it takes parameters
       // here set your fields that are not part of the super class
    }
}
```

---

Most important -- there's no need to guess at this since great resources are available that will show you how to use and create constructors, including:

- [Providing Constructors for Your Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)
- [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

---

**Edit**

> 1. Read each disk record, create the corresponding object (Circle or Rectangle), add the object to a dynamic array called list.

Your instructions tell you that you're going to need to create and fill an `ArrayList<GeometricObject>`. Where is your ArrayList?

> 2. Nicely print the contents of the list (indicate position and content).

This tells you that all of your classes will need a decent `toString()` method to allow for easy and clean output.

> 3. Write a method to find the position on the list holding the largest element (biggest area of them all).

The abstract super GeometricObject class will need an `abstract public double getArea()` method, and each child class will need to implement that method so that it returns a calculated area. Then you'll need to create a static method that iterates through the ArrayList, finding the largest area in your list.

> 4. Print the position and data (including area) of the selected object (main method).

The method above should return the largest GeometricObject on the list, and then you'll need to output its properties.

> 5. Write a method to find the position on the list holding the largest element of a given color (try “RED”).

Another method, similar to the one above, but that looks at both the color String returned by `getColor()` and the double returned by `getArea()`.

> 6. Print the position and data (including area) of the selected object – if any!

Self-explanatory

> The following are signatures of methods you need to write

The following is all self explanatory

So yes, you **will need** three classes, an abstract GeometricObject that has an `abstract public double getArea();` method signature, that has a name String (actually may not be necessary), a color String, a boolean field, and a constructor that accepts the name, color, and boolean (although again, name may not be necessary since that String tells you which child class to use). And then you will need two child classes, each with their own fields, a double radius field for Circle, doubles sideA and sideB for Rectangle, and constructors that accept this information plus the information needed for the super class's constructor.